# How to convert a matrix to a list using List Comprehension

Tags: python, pytorch

`dataset[i][j]` is a 100x30 matrix.

And I want to convert to a list using list comprehension.

I tried
`train_dataset = [dataset[i][j] for i,j in [range(30), range(100)]]`

but there was an error : `ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)`

How could I assign the conversion, so `len(train_dataset)=3000` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I got this right, dataset is a matrix, with size 100x30, and you are trying to get a list from it?

If this is the case, you can do:

```
dataset = [[x for x in range(30)] for j in range(100)]
train_dataset = [dataset[i][j] for i in range(100) for j in range(30)]

print(train_dataset)
print(len(train_dataset))
```

dataset will be:

```
[0, ..., 29]
[0, ..., 29]
    x100
[0, ..., 29]
```

and your output will be:

```
[0, ..., 29, 0, ..., 29... x100]
```

resulting an array of size 3000.